# Users' profile URL

Tags: php

I want to make a profile for my users (not to update their profile settings; I already did that) that other users can also see.

I thought of passing id in URL for `user_id`, but if the user changes the id in the URL the profile will change as well. Anyone can suggest a better approach?

```
<a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $user_id; ?>">Profile</a>
```

Comment: If it's a public profile, what's the issue with changing ID to see other people's profiles?
Apart from that - you can generate a unique hash for a given user and use that instead, so it cannot be easily guessed.

Comment: That is pretty much the standard approach for publicly accessible pages.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest using another php page for the profile user using this :

```
<? 
session_start();
$_SESSION['username']=$username;
?>
```

and then include it in your a href link by using

```
<? include('page.php') ; ?>
```